Enable Pan/Zoom in QGraphicsView
I'm using Python and QtDesigner to display camera images with an overlay.
My MainWindow gives access to camera settings, and trigger the camera accordingly. It sends each image via pyQtSlot to a QGraphicsView.
How can I enable zoom in this QGraphicView?
I've read the answer at How to enable Pan and Zoom in a QGraphicsView
It works well for a frozen picture, but when I send the next image the zoom resets.
Here is my working code (so without my attempts to implement zoom):
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QWidget, QGraphicsPixmapItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPainter, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF, pyqtSlot, Qt

class Display(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._empty = True
        self.image_qt = QImage()
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.pic = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self.pic)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    def hasPicture(self):
        return not self._empty

    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def on_image_received(self, image: QImage, scale: float, x_offset: int, y_offset: int):
        # Scale the overlay, Adjust the position
        # self.image_qt = set_calque(image, scale, x_offset, y_offset)
        # not useful for a minimal example, so skip the overlay part:
        self.image_qt = image

        # Image size
        image_width = self.image_qt.width()
        image_height = self.image_qt.height()

        # Return if we don't have an image yet
        if image_width == 0 or image_height == 0:
            return

        self._empty = False
        self.pic.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image_qt))
        self.fitInView(QRectF(0, 0, image_width, image_height), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.update()


After several tries I got it to almost work: I think the zoom is not well centered on the mouse position, but I can't get why.
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QWidget, QGraphicsPixmapItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPainter, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF, pyqtSlot, Qt, QPoint


class Display(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 1
        self._pt = QPoint()
        self._empty = True
        self.image_qt = QImage()
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.pic = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self.pic)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    def hasPicture(self):
        return not self._empty

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        # self.pt = self.mapToScene(event.pos()).toPoint()
        self._pt = event.pos()
        if self.hasPicture():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.2
                self._zoom *= factor
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom *= factor
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)

    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def on_image_received(self, image: QImage, scale: float, x_offset: int, y_offset: int):
        # overlay the image. Scale the overlay, Adjust its position
        self.image_qt = set_calque(image, scale, x_offset, y_offset)

        # Image size
        image_width = self.image_qt.width()
        image_height = self.image_qt.height()

        # Return if we don't have an image yet
        if image_width == 0 or image_height == 0:
            return

        self._empty = False
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.pic.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image_qt))
        self.fitInView()
        self.update()

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QRectF(self.pic.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            if not self._pt.isNull() and self._zoom > 1:
                rect.moveCenter(self._pt)
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPicture():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                factor *= self._zoom
                self.scale(factor, factor)

